# Wordpress Custom Post Type and sort by Tags

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, loop, tags

I am currently making a custom Wordpress theme, but so far I am stuck at this little problem. I have created this custom post type. And in that page *(media.php)* I want to be able to click on the tags, which will take me to the tag page *(tag.php)* and from there it will only show the post under that tag I clicked on, but right now if I click on tag 1, it will take me to **tag.php**, but will show **ALL** media post, instead of the page with clicked tag.

I have made a Custom Post type in **functions.php**

***add Custom Post Type (functions.php)***

```
add_action( 'init', 'media_' );
function media_() {
register_post_type( 'media', array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Media Post',
    'singular_name' => 'Media',
   ),
  'description' => 'The Media.',
  'public' => true,
  'menu_position' => 21,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor'),
  'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')

));
}
```

and then my page custom page template will loop the tags like this

***loop the tags in custom page template (media.php)***

```
 <ul>
    <?php   
    $archive_tags = post_type_tags( 'media' );

    foreach( $archive_tags as $tag ) 
        {
                echo '<li><ahref="' 
                          . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id )
                          . '">' 
                          . esc_html( $tag->name ) 
                          . '</a></li>';
        }
   ?>  
   </ul>
```

and then I will loop through all the custom post with the post_type name *'Media'*

***Loop the post (media.php)***

```
<?php   
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Media');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>                             
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

this work, I can see all the different tags, and the post in media.php. But the thing is when I go to tag.php. It just shows all the post in media.php with that post_type name.

What should I write in **tag.php**?

For reference, my code in tag.php look like this so far. and it looks just like media.php.

***looping the post, dosn't work (tag.php)***

```
  <?php     
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Media');
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>                             
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

*Example*

**Media.php**

1. Post 1, *tag: **a**, **b***
2. Post 2, *tag: **a***
3. Post 3, *tag: **b***

*then there is this list with all the tags available*

- tag **a**
- tag **b**

*so lets say I click on tag **a***.
*It will rederict me to **tag.php***

But instead of showing me all the post like this

1. Post 1, *tag: a, **b***
2. Post 3, *tag: **b***
   it is showing all the post from **media.php**.

*NOTE* **
I only want it to display the post from my custom-post-type: **Media**

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Please clarify what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve, what you've tried yourself so far and what problems you're running into.

Comment: Well you have `'post_type`'=> 'Media'` which tells your `tag.php` to only show posts under the post type `Media`. What are you trying to show on `tag.php`?

Comment: Greetings both, I have tried to make it more clear in my post. thanks for taking your  time!